# PHP encoding nested array as object

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to get a list of year and month from PHP to my web site page. The website works with JavaScript, so I need this data to be JSON.

There is no problem to generate the information I need, but I use `json_encode` on the PHP, all the nested arrays turn into object and because of this, I can't have the proper behavior on the JavaScript.

This is what I'm doing to generate the array on the PHP:

```
$list = sql("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(created) AS year FROM order");

foreach ($list as &$row) {
    $row['month'] = array();

    for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
        $row['month'][$i] = new stdClass();
        $row['month'][$i]->Month = date("M", strtotime(date("Y")."-".$i."-01"));

        //more information goes here...
    }
}
```

If I just print the `$list` using `return print_r($list);` this is the result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [year] => 2016
        [month] => Array (
            [1] => stdClass Object (
                [Month] => Jan
            )
            [2] => stdClass Object (
                [Month] => Feb
            )
            //Etc...
```

But when I use

```
return print_r(json_encode($list));
//or
return print_r(json_encode($list, true));
```

All the nested array turn into object. For example, the Month array, turn into an object, this is a print screen of the `console.log` of the result:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you cannot have arrays starting at index 1. If you want an array, your indices will have to be 0 - 11.

Comment: @deceze simple as that! Was so focused on the other part, forgot about this detail.. Thank you. If you can turn it into an answer, so I can accept. Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather first create the month-object and then add it to the array like that: `$row['month'][] = $monthObj;`

Comment: @deceze you can have an array starting from what index you want. If you don't specify the starting index, it will be zero, but he does specify it.

Comment: @besciualex …in *JSON!*

Comment: @deceze indeed :D

Answer (score 0):

If you just need month names, then replace these rows:

```
$row['month'][$i] = new stdClass();
$row['month'][$i]->Month = date("M", strtotime(date("Y")."-".$i."-01"));
```

With this:

```
$row['month'][$i] = date("M", strtotime(date("Y")."-".$i."-01"));
```

You don't need a STD object for what you are tring to accomplish.

Comment: I need more information, but since it's not relevant to the question, I omitted the code.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Ask here, or reedit your question. What is the thing you don't understand?

Comment: Look at deceze comment, he answered the question.